# google mock link error with mocking C function

Tags: c++, c, googletest, googlemock

I have the following code, I try to mock a C function using google mock:

This is the header file:

```
A.h

int getValue(int age, int* value, int* number);
```

This is the source file:

```
A.c

int getValue(int age, int* value, int* number)
{
    // do something and return value
    return 10;
}
```

This is source file b.c, which using a.h

```
b.c

#include <a.h>

void formValue()
{
   int b = 10;
   int c = 20;
   getValue(1, &b, &c);    
}
```

This is the mock file:

```
AMock.hh

#include "a.h"

class AFileMock {
  public:
    AFileMock();
    ~AFileMock();
    MOCK_METHOD3(getValue, int(int, int *, int *));
};
```

Then in the test:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include <b.h>
#include <AFileMock.h>

using testing::_;
using testing::Return;
using testing::InSequence;

class BTest: public testing::Test {

protected:
   AFileMock aFile;

public:
   void SetUp() { }
   void TearDown() { }
};


TEST_F(BTest, test1)
{
   InSequence sequence;
   EXPECT_CALL(aFile, getValue(_, _, _)).
      Times(1);

   formValue();
}
```

when I try to run this test, it complains that the get link error in the Mock file, it says:

`link error: getValue(_, _, _) is not defined`, and it points to the Mock file `AMock.hh`.

But if I use MOCK_CONST_METHOD instead of MOCK_METHOD in the Mock, it work:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD3(getValue, int(int, int *, int *));
```

No complier errors.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The source code is in C

Comment: please remove the 'c' tag.

Comment: the a.h header file is missing the 'include guards'.  (typically: #ifndef A_H  #define A_H ..... #endif)    Please use meaningful names. 'a.h' is not a meaningful name, nor is 'b.c'

Comment: @ratzip has something left unclear to you?

Comment: @fukanchik thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
AMock.hh

#include "a.h"
```

with

```
AMock.hh

extern "C" {
    #include "a.h"
}
```

here is why: [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)